# How to convert p12 file to base64 string?

Tags: ios, notifications, base64, push

I'm using [java apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) to push notification to ios devices on my server, Java apns needs a .p12 certificates and password when pushing notification.

```
ApnsService service =
APNS.newService()
.withCert("/path/to/certificate.p12", "MyCertPassword")
.withSandboxDestination()
.build();
```

I want to store this type of .p12 into my database since I have more than 1 .p12 files in my system. Our server also allows the third-party to submit their apps to our server.  They are required to submit their .p12 files to our server since they want to push notification via our server. We don't want to keep their .p12 files into a folder on our server but database with a base64 string.

I have somequestions here:
How can we convert a .p12 into a base64 string? 
How can we restore the .p12 file from a base64 string when I push notification?
Is there any better solutions to get and store .p2 files on my server side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    File file = new File(fileName);
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);

    return encodedString;
}
private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
           && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```